# Add another html in callback (jsPDF)

Tags: reactjs, package, jspdf

I am stuck in jsPDF package. i want to print html to pdf.

```
const toPdf = () => {
    let doc = new jsPDF("p", "px", "a4");
    doc.html(document.querySelector("#printdiv"), {
      callback: function (pdf) {
        
        pdf.save("preview.pdf");
      },
    });
  };


<button onClick={toPdf()}></button>
```

it is a simple to print html in pdf but the problem is that when i want to print another html in callback so i did not get any response from this. no page created and no any html print on page.